# Получение координат по адресу в MapView

Tags: android

Существует ли способ получить координаты по адресу? скажем "г.Киев, Ул Ленина 1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же есть.
Например, [прямой запрос гуглу](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru)

Ну или средствами GeoCoder`a, пример кода можно [тут глянуть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)